# Возможно ли сделать склонение числительных окончаний в слове "секунд"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Возможно ли сделать склонение числительных окончаний в слове "секунд", и если да, то как это правильно сделать? Очень вам благодарен за помощь!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.timer').prepend('<div class="left">Окно можно будет закрыть через <span></span> секунд</div>');
decOfNum(5, ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']);
  var delay = 1,
    seconds = 7;
  $('.left span').text(seconds);
  $('.pop_up').delay(delay * 1000).fadeIn(800, function() {
    var int;
    int = setInterval(function() {
      if (seconds > 1) {
        $('.left span').text(seconds - 1);
        seconds--;
      } else {
        $('.left').remove();
        $('.pop_up .close').show();
        clearInterval(int);
      }
    }, 1000);
$('.timer').ready(function (declOfNum(number, titles) {
cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];  
return titles[ (number%100>4 && number%100<20)? 2 : cases[(number%10<5)?number%10:5] ];  
});
  });
});
jQuery('.close').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 jQuery('.pop_up').fadeOut(0);
});
```

```css
.pop_up {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
}

.close {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pop_up">Я модальное окно
  <div class="timer">
    <div class="close">Закрыть окно</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ты серьезно? ты вот абсолютно серьезно? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/545410/191482 ... угадай, кто автор того вопроса?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно внести изменения в скрипт таймера обратного отсчета времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545410/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8)

Comment: Вариант для php https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/89458/186083

Comment: я бы написал "сек." и для этого мне надо 0 строчек кода

Comment: @LADYX и там и здесь - изменение окончаний числительных. причем там еще и конкурсные 50 репутации отдано правильному решению. ты не в состоянии применить подобное  решение у себя? или ищешь копи паст без возможности думать?

Comment: @LADYX  `но выше своей планки перепрыгнуть, извините сэр` - так у тебя уже есть готовое решение. ровно то, что ты хочешь и здесь и сейчас спрашиваешь. просто берешь то и применяешь этого. тут даже думать особо не надо........`для кого тут эти картинки` - это называется пиар, для заманухи. делай выводы.

Answer (score 6):

Простая функция:

```js
function case_num(titles){
    var cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
    return function(number){
      number = Math.abs(number);
      let c = 
       (number%100>4 && number%100<20)? 2 :
          cases[(number%10<5) ? number%10 : 5];
      return  titles[c];
    }
}

const f = case_num(['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']);
[
  0, 4, 5, 11, 21, 25
].forEach(num => console.log(num, f(num)))
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/realmyst/1262561)

Comment: написать чтоль третий ответ с ссылкой на тот же гист :D

Answer (score 3):

Можно

```js
function declOfNum(number, titles) {
  cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return titles[(number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[(number % 10 < 5) ? number % 10 : 5]];
}
alert(declOfNum(21, ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']));
```

**[Источник](https://gist.github.com/realmyst/1262561)**