# День, дня, дней JS выражение

Tags: javascript, числа

Подскажите нужна функция на JavaScript, которая бы на входе принимала число и выводила бы склонение слова "день".
Срок изготовления [364] дня или [1] день.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Возможно ли сделать склонение числительных окончаний в слове "секунд"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708558/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function createLabel(number, titles) {
    const cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
    return `${titles[number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20 ? 2 : cases[number % 10 < 5 ? number % 10 : 5]]}`;
}

console.log(createLabel(1, ['День', 'Дня', 'Дней']));
console.log(createLabel(3, ['День', 'Дня', 'Дней']));
console.log(createLabel(7, ['День', 'Дня', 'Дней']));
console.log(createLabel(99, ['День', 'Дня', 'Дней']));
console.log(createLabel(101, ['День', 'Дня', 'Дней']));
console.log(createLabel(102, ['День', 'Дня', 'Дней']));
```

Comment: А зачем `${}`? Можно же просто вернуть значение. Зачем 5 элемент cases?  `... number % 10 < 5? number % 10 : 0`

Comment: У меня этот код используется в приложении. Детально я его не разбирал и сюда вставил, убрав свою внутреннюю логику. Думаю тот, кто задавал вопрос сможет сам отредактировать вывод под свои нужны :)

Answer (score 3):

Вот наипростейшее решение:

```
function dayTitle(number) {
    if (number > 10 && [11, 12, 13, 14].includes(number%100)) return 'дней';
    last_num = number%10;
    if (last_num == 1) return 'день';
    if ([2,3,4].includes(last_num)) return 'дня';
    if ([5,6,7,8,9, 0].includes(last_num)) return 'дней';
}
```

Через остаток от деления получаем последнюю цифру числа и по ней понимаем склонение слова.

UPD: добавил проверку на случай, если число оканчивается на 11, 12, 13, 14

Comment: @Kromster, неа)

Answer (score 1):

Мне нравится считать начиная с 0. Такой счёт позволяет получить все три формы подряд 0 -- дней, 1 -- день, 2 -- дня. Можно написать функцию, которая вернёт 0, 1 или 2 в зависимости от значения числа.

```
console.log(['дней', 'день', 'дня'][plural(100500)])
```

Если немного посчитать дни, то можно заметить, что

- "дней" -- всё что заканчивается на 0 или 5-19,
- то что заканчивается на 2-4 -- "дня",
- остальное -- "день".

Чтобы узнать на что заканчивается число, можно посмотреть на остаток от деления на 10 и 100 в нашем случае.

Разделите сразу, а потом используйте if {} else if {} else {} (воспользуйтесь тернарным оператором, если вам нравится компактность).

Написать такую функцию -- полезное упражнение для новичка. Не лишайте себя удовольствия и опыта, копируя чужое решение. А если вам надо для работы то гуглите "js plural" или типа того (например, можете обнаружить [Intl.PluralRules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/PluralRules)).

Comment: А допустим, 115 дней все таки?

Comment: 115  заканчивается на 5-19, значит "дней". Или вы о чём?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин, согласен с тем, что не стоит лишать себя удовольствия изобрести решение